# How to disable debug logging based on $location.host?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to disable debug logging based on the host address. For instance, I want to keep debug logging for DEV and QA instances and disable console debug logs on productions. Currently, the way to disable debug logs is by using

> $logProvider.enableDebug(false)

I want this call only on a specific URL and `$location` is not available where `$logProvider` is available.

Comment: Did you try my proposed solution below ? Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain old JS `window.location.host`. E.g.:

```
var listOfDebugEnabledHosts = [...];
app.config(function ($logProvider) {
  var host = window.location.host;
  var debugEnabled = listOfDebugEnabledHosts.indexOf(host) !== -1;
  $logProvider.debugEnabled(debugEnabled);
});
```

Comment: This works and should be the accepted answer. I just added my local development machine (eg: "localhost:12345") and testing server to the list of debug enabled hosts and I only receive $log.debug messages on those hosts. Too bad you have no out of the box control over $log.log, $log.info etc...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using: https://github.com/sunnykgupta/jsLogger

Features:

- It safely overrides the console.log. Takes care if the console is not available (oh yes, you need to factor that too.)
- Stores all logs (even if they are suppressed) for later retrieval.
- Handles major console functions like log, warn, error, info.
- Is open for modifications and will be updated whenever new suggestions come up.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the plugin.